# JSF 2.2 Ajax Render Custom Component

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2.2, custom-component

I am working on a component library for JSF 2.2 for use in applications that also are using the Twitter Bootstrap 3 CSS framework.  Since Bootstrap 3 can be a little verbose in the amount of `<div>` tags and other containers you have to wrap forms and form controls in to apply CSS styles nicely, I'm creating custom components that can render all of that with a single tag.

My approach, that had been working up until this point was to extend an existing JSF component, and override the `encodeBegin()` and `encodeEnd()` methods, and add the necessary `<div>` elements that the Bootstrap framework requires.  I also call `super.encodeBegin()` and `super.encodeEnd()` in the overridden methods to leverage the existing rendering of the component I am enhancing. This has been working well except for the case when I want to render one of my custom components via an `<f:ajax>` tag's `render` attribute.  When I specify the id of my custom component to the `render` attribute, debugging reveals the entire component's `encodeBegin()` and `encodeEnd()` methods are called, but only the actual `<input>` element itself is being updated on the page and not all of the markup surrounding it.

This behavior makes sense since the id attribute I specify on my custom tag gets passed on to the `<input>` element.  How can I specify a separate ID field for my custom component?  I had considered possibly I should not be extending `HTMLInputText` and utilizing its rendering by calling `super.encodeBegin()` and `super.encodeEnd()`, but logically I don't want to create a whole new components from scratch, but just enhance the existing JSF ones.  Also I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel to make sure I support all of `<h:inputText>`'s attributes since I would like my components to be drop-in replacements for the JSF components.

I realize composite components might be simpler and might not suffer from this issue, but during rendering, I need to access the `FacesContext` to check for messages as the renderers for my custom components will attach different Bootstrap classes and possibly insert entire new `<span>` elements based on the validation state of the component.  I am not sure how to accomplish this with a composite component (without requesting the info from a backing bean).

Is there another approach I can use that would allow me to leverage existing JSF components?